# If $\aleph_\alpha=\alpha$, then $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, ordinals

> If $\aleph_\alpha=\alpha$, then $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal.

**My attempt:**

Assume the contrary that $\alpha$ is not a limit ordinal. Then $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal and thus $\alpha=\beta+1$ for a unique $\beta$.

It follows that $\beta \bigcup\{\beta\}=\aleph_\alpha$. Thus $|\aleph_\alpha|=|\beta|$ or $\aleph_\alpha=|\beta|$. This means $\aleph_\alpha$ is equipotent to a smaller ordrinal. This is clearly a contradiction.

---

My proof is quite short and I wonder if it contains any logical flaw/gap. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your argument follows. In general, any infinite cardinal is a limit ordinal.

Comment: Oh i forget that. Many thanks!